# socket.io not work on Chrome 16 and Firefox 9

Tags: socket.io

I've just tried running the chat sample of socket.io 0.8.7, it works fine with IE 8 on my PC (WinXP SP3). However, when running on Chrome 16 or FF 9, the page only displays " Connecting to socket.io server ".

There are some logs displayed on console:

```
   app listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized 1463707665737450199
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/1463707665737450199
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client 1463707665737450199
   debug - client authorized for
   debug - websocket writing 1::
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/1463707665737450199?t=13
27157804923
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client 1463707665737450199
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/jsonp-polling/1463707665737450199?t=
1327157814924&i=0
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - jsonppolling writing io.j[0]("8::");
   debug - set close timeout for client 1463707665737450199
   debug - jsonppolling closed due to exceeded duration
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/jsonp-polling/1463707665737450199?t=
1327157834951&i=0
   debug - setting poll timeout
   debug - discarding transport
   debug - cleared close timeout for client 1463707665737450199
   debug - clearing poll timeout
   debug - jsonppolling writing io.j[0]("8::");
   debug - set close timeout for client 1463707665737450199
   debug - jsonppolling closed due to exceeded duration
```

I'm 100% new  to socket.io so I don't know what wrong with it. Hope for your help.

Thanks & best regard,

Comment: Are you trying it on a local page? I mean, does the url start with file://

Comment: @Shvelo no, I run it with node.js server. I think there're a problem with Websocket protocol cause it run normally when I remove 'websocket' in 'transports' config. Hope for your help! Thanks.

Comment: did you ever solved this issue?